# can't get right url to serve admin-uploaded image django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I'm trying to get a template to display images uploaded through the admin interface, and I've had zero luck with it. I've tried looking through the pre-existing questions on this topic, and none have helped.

Below is my settings, models, view, and template file

**settings.py**

```
import os
from os import path
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))






DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
PROJECT_DIR_PATH = path.dirname(path.normpath(path.abspath(__file__)))




INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'about.apps.AboutConfig',
    'forms.apps.FormsConfig',
    'resources.apps.ResourcesConfig',
    'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'nydkcd11.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'nydkcd11.wsgi.application'




DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}




AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Division(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    school = models.CharField(max_length = 75)
    position = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    desc = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
def division(request):
    member_list = Division.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'about/division.html',{'member_list':member_list})
    return HttpResponse("this is the divison page")
```

**division.html**

```
<h1>Divisional Board Members</h1>
{% for member in member_list%}
    <h2>{{member.name}}</h2>
    <h3>{{member.school}}</h3>
    <h3>{{member.position}}</h3>
    <img src = "{{member.image.url}}">
    <p>{{member.desc}}</p>
    <p>{{MEDIA.ROOT}}</p>
    <p>{{MEDIA.URL}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The specific problem that comes up is that the full directory is not generated. For example, the url I'll get will be `media/images/example.jpg`, but doesn't include the full absolute path. This has (unsurprisingly) prevented `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/example.jpg` from working. Could someone  demonstrate how I should go about getting the full path for the template to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

put this in your urls.py

Comment: well that means you are providing the url of your project to the image url, without this the image only gets the path from the media folder to image name, this adds the url at front of your image